# how to get partial data from ajax from long time php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a 1 PHP script that takes about 2 minutes to complete several process.
I need to bring to the user when every step in that process is complete.
i do this before loading a iframe where the PHP has a  lavel every time one step is complete and that work fine, but now i need to do that throw ajax.
is there a way to exeute a function based on partial ajax query?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try multiple ajax requests each sequentially calling one another and returning data to the user at each successful request?  It would seem that is exactly what you're looking for.